# Why is -d used instead of -m for most neuter pronouns

Tags: pronouns, ending, neuter

There is a notable set of pronouns that use -d for the neuter nominative and accusative:

- iste > istud
- ille > illud
- quis > quid
- is > id

Other pronouns do not:

- hic > hoc
- ipse > ipsum (though L&S lists once instance of ipsud)

My question is more in the realm of linguistics: **Is there a reason why (only?) these pronouns use -d for the neuter?** The answer may be as simple as pointing to the PIE derivative, though I'm also curious why this -d does not occur in neuter nouns of the second and (I believe) third declension.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There isn't really an answer to the "why" question beyond the fact that in Proto-Indo-European, some of the case endings for pronouns were different from those for nouns, for unknown reasons. Among these is the nom./acc. sg. neuter ending, which was *-d instead of *-m. This is clear from cognates in other languages, e.g. Sanskrit neuter demonstrative *tad*, neuter relative *yad*, etc. (The Greek cognates of these two forms are τό, ὅ, which also descend from *-d, since final stops were lost in Greek.)

Another specifically pronominal case ending, by the way, is the masculine plural *-oi, which in Latin (and in Greek) spread from pronouns to nouns, giving the familiar second-declension ending *-ī.*

*Ipsum* is presumably analogical on the nominal declension. *Hoc* actually did once contain the *-d: it's from *hod-ce, and in fact seems to have been pronounced *hocc*, which is why it scans long in verse.

Comment: Interesting! I didn't know that *hoc* scans long in verse, and that lead me to ask [a follow-up question](http://latin.stackexchange.com/q/2538/79).

Comment: Happy to see you to 10k.

Comment: @C.M.Weimer, gratias tibi ago!