# Words that unexpectedly but consistently scan long

Tags: classical-latin, poetry, scansion, metre

I learned from TKR's answer to [this question about neuter endings](https://latin.stackexchange.com/q/2536/79) that the neuter pronoun *hoc* is pronounced like *hocc*, causing it to be scanned long despite having a short vowel.
I had never heard of this before, but I want to understand better.
This leads me to some questions:

- Can you provide a couple of examples of nominative or accusative *hoc* followed by a vowel and scanned long?
- Are there examples in classical poetry that treat *hoc* normally, scanning it short before a vowel?
- Are there other words that unexpectedly scan long always or often? I suspect the suffix *-ce* might lead to this effect. This question includes other forms of the same pronoun, especially the masculine *hic*.

Comment: I found a relevant passage in Bennett (1907) that I summarize in my answer to [What effect should a macron have on the sound of a letter and its word?](http://latin.stackexchange.com/questions/5/what-effect-should-a-macron-have-on-the-sound-of-a-letter-and-its-word/17#17). He thinks it is likely that a long final consonant occured in some nominative forms where original -s was assimilated to a preceding s, l, or r, as in *far, farris.* I'm unsure about the extent to which this is supported by metrical evidence.

Comment: @sumelic Interesting! It could be that dictionaries mark some vowels length due to metric evidence but the authors have misinterpreted a long consonant for a long vowel. A short study of words of this kind would constitute a nice answer.

Comment: Is **far** long from Synizesis?

Comment: @Hugh I don't know about *far*. That's a potential answer word. By *hic* I mean the one with short vowel, hence the word "masculine".

Comment: Not an easy one to diagnose, because by default a heavy syllable preceding a single consonant is grounds to just classify the vowel as long.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*Hoc* is always scanned long in classical poetry, because it is the same as *hocc (from *hocce < *hodce). I give only a couple of examples, but you can check by yourself using http://www.pedecerto.eu/ricerca/forma. It is the same for the other words formed with the intensifying particle -ce, like *istuc* (from *istucce < *istudce) or *illuc* (from *illucce < *illudce)

> Lucil. *sat.* 1032: ***hoc*** etiam accipe quod dico: nam pertinet ad
>   rem
>
> Verg. *ecl.* 1,539: *Quod genus **hoc** hominum? quaeue hunc tam barbara
>   morem*

Concerning other words which present the same gemination phenomenon, there are:

- words from -rr, like ***cor*** (from *cord), which is scanned long by archaic authors only (e.g. Plaut. *Pers.* 802 [quaternary cataleptic anapest] ***cor*** uritur, caput ne ardescat, but already in Lucil. sat. 516 is scanned short: *vera putant, credunt signis **cor** inesse in aenis*), or ***ter*** (from *terr, cfr. the compound *terruncius*);
- words from -ss (from the assimilation of the dental conosonant of the stem and the -s of the first person nominative singular desinence), like ***miles, compos, dives, eques, hospes, impos*** et similia, or in ***es*** (second person singular of *sum*, from *ess), cfr. e.g. Plaut. *Aul.* 528 (iambic senarius): ***miles*** impransus astat, aes censet dari; Plaut. *Cas.* 817 (iambic senarius): ***sospes*** iter incipe hoc, uti viro tuo; but already in Ennius these syllables are scanned short (e.g. *ann.* 269: *spernitur orator bonus, horridus **miles** amatur*).

Vd. M. Leumann, *Lateinische Laut- und Formenlehre*, München 1977, pp. 220-221; S. Boldrini, *La prosodia e la metrica dei Romani*, Roma 1992, pp. 50-51.