# Where does the word "tudes" 'hammer' show up in texts?

Tags: vocabulary, declension, noun

[Lewis and Short](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus:text:1999.04.0059:entry=tudes) has an entry for a noun *tŭdes,* with the genitive singular given as "is (ĭtis, acc. to Fest. p. 253 Müll.)". It is defined as "a hammer, mallet". The two citations in the entry show the forms *tudites* and *tudibus*:

> “tudites malleos appellant antiqui a tundendo,” Fest. p. 352 sq. Müll.: fabriles operae tudibus contundere massas Festinant, Auct. Aetnae, 659.

I understand the first quote to be saying that *tudites* is an old word for *malleos,* so I'm unsure whether the word was even really in use in Classical Latin.

The main thing I'm wondering is where the nominative *tudes* and genitive *tudis* are attested. I tried to search for them in the PHI Latin Texts corpus, but nothing came up. Also, the [Wiktionary entry](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/tudes) and a [blog post](https://latinforaddicts.wordpress.com/2013/05/17/i-stems-mixed-i-stems-58/) I found indicate the existence of an i-stem genitive plural *tudium,* but I likewise cannot figure out where this is attested. What kinds of Latin texts used the word *tudes*? Can anyone provide quotes that use the other forms aside from the accusative plural *tudites* and ablative plural *tudibus*?

Answer (score 5):

I wouldn't take Wiktionary's declension tables too seriously. They're algorithmically generated, and don't necessarily imply that any particular form is attested.

In this case, I haven't been able to find any attested forms apart from the *tuditēs* and *tudibus* you cited. So any singular forms would have to be back-derived from there.

The genitive singular is nice and easy to predict: we can cut off the plural endings to get the stems *tudit-* and *tud-*, then add the third-declension *-is*, to get **tuditis* and **tudis*. This is what L&S have done. All plural forms and most singular forms are built off the same "apparent stem", whether or not it's the same as the underlying stem, since all those endings "react" the same way.

The nominative singular is a bit more difficult. On the face of it, we would expect to just put the third-declension ending *-s* on the end of the stem, then apply regular sound-change laws: **tudit-s* > **tudīs* > **tudis* (cf *lapid-s* > *lapīs* > *lapis* "stone", nom pl *lapidēs*), or **tud-s* > **tūs* (cf *ped-s* > *pēs* "foot", dat pl *pedibus*).

However, due to vowel reduction, *we can't actually be certain of the vowel in the stem*: it's also possible the original stem was **tudet-*, which would give a nominative singular **tudēs* > **tudes*, but the same plural **tudet-ēs* > *tuditēs* (cf *milet-s* > *milēs* > *miles* "soldier", nom pl *militēs*).

*Or*, instead of ending in a consonant, this word could have been an *i*-stem **tudi-*, in which case the nominative would be either **tudis* or **tudēs*, but have the same plural **tudi-ibus* > *tudibus* (cf *vāti-s* > *vātis*/*vātēs* "bard", dat pl *vātibus*).

L&S seem to have considered the form **tudes* and/or **tudēs* the most reasonable (conveniently leaving off the vowel length), and chosen it as their reconstruction. Which makes sense to me: nouns declining like *vātēs* and *miles* are significantly more common in Latin than nouns declining like *pēs* or *lapis*. Moreover, it would explain how we see both *tuditēs* and *tudibus*: it was presumably an obscure word, so an alternation between **tudes* and **tudēs* isn't too far-fetched (especially since we see this sort of vowel alternation in better-attested third-declension nouns too). Some people used it one way and ended up with *tuditēs*, some used the other way and ended up with *tudibus*, and the word as a whole ended up with two different declension patterns. (However, I'd still have marked it with a star, personally.)

As for the short *ŭ* in the stem, I'm guessing that's for etymological reasons. Compare *tut**ŭ**dī* "I have hit", *st**ŭ**deō* "I dedicate myself to". This noun seems to have come from the same root, and would be expected to have the same vowel quantity.

Comment: Thanks. I hadn't thought about how the root being the same as *tutŭdī* could imply that the vowel was short. That makes sense. However, couldn't a different ablaut grade of the same root (like *ew or *ow) lead to a long vowel? I'm not sure at what time eu and ou changed to ū, or whether there is a general principle that such nouns are built on the zero grade rather than the e- or o- grade of a root.

Comment: @sumelic Both fair points! I'll recheck my vowel lengths in endings.

Comment: Another small note about vowel length: I'm not sure that it's correct to reconstruct a stage with compensatory vowel lengthening for all nouns that show -s for -ds or -ts in the nominative singular. *Pes* is an unusual word, considering that it's not a regular reflex of the reconstructed PIE nominative at all. De Vaan (citing Jasanoff 2004: 414) says that the vowel in *pes* could have been lengthened by Lachmann's Law, which would not be expected to apply to roots ending in t.

Comment: Alessio's post that I linked to below fdb's answer suggests that heavy scansion of the last syllable *sospes* etc. in older sources was caused by a word-final long consonant.

Comment: [Jasanoff 2008](http://www.people.fas.harvard.edu/~jasanoff/pdf/Lachmann's%20Law.pdf), available online, seems to give an overview of Jasanoff's opinion on the contexts where Lachmann's law-type vowel lengthening applied.

Answer (score 4):

Just making a post to hold a few more things I found out since asking the question.

#### This noun is likely related to *touiller* (Fr.), *tudiculare,* and *tudicula*

There is a French verb *touiller* 'toss', whose *ou* points to Latin short *ŭ,* which is thought to be derived from a Latin first-conjugation verb *tŭdĭculō, tŭdĭcŭlāre.* The Latin verb is thought to be derived from a feminine noun *[tŭdĭcŭla](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus:text:1999.04.0059:entry=tudicula), -ae* 'a small machine for bruising olives' (L&S). *Tudicula* seems to be used only once in the PHI classical corpus, in the line cited by L&S from Columella's *De Re Rustica* 12.52.7.2:

> est et organum erectae tribulae simile, quod **tudicula** uocatur, idque non incommode opus efficit, nisi quod frequenter uitiatur et, si bacae plusculum ingesseris, inpeditur.

L&S explain *tudicula* as a diminutive of *tudes,* although that violates the general rule saying that diminutives of masculine nouns are masculine (and take *-ulus* rather than *-ula* unless the original noun was a first-declension noun). The document "[Oscilaciones entre género masculino y femenino documentadas en latín medieval](https://eprints.ucm.es/3370/1/T20471.pdf)", by Francisco González Luis, mentions that the non-feminine forms *tudiculum* and *tudiculi* were also used at some point.

While this still seems to me like fairly scanty evidence about the form (*)*tudes* itself, it supports the reconstruction of a short vowel, which was something that I expressed doubt about in the comments.

#### Tuditanus

The name *[Tuditanus](http://dml.cmnh.org/2014Dec/msg00108.html)* has been supposed to be connected to the noun meaning 'hammer'.

#### The nominative singular form *tudes* is definitely attested in post-classical sources

The form *Tudes* itself seems to have been used as an epithet for the individual also known as *Carolus Martellus,* or in French *Charles Martel,* whose life spanned the 7th and 8th centuries. I don't know what the earliest attestation of this is; I found two examples from the 17th century, in books from 1656 (*[Thuani Enucleati Pars IV.](https://books.google.com/books?id=cplAAAAAcAAJ&pg=PA58&lpg=PA58&dq=carolus+tudes),* p. 58: "Carolus Tudes sive Martellus") and 1651 (*[Almagesti novi pars posterior tomi primi](https://books.google.com/books?id=XY8yK6eW4sQC&pg=PR3&lpg=PR3&dq=charles+martel+tudes+carolus+Carolus+Martellus),* page iii: "Carolus verò Martellus, seu Tudes,").

In 1822, a species of fish was given the scientific name *Zygaena tudes* by Valenciennes (but the [taxonomy seems to have been revised since then](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smalleye_hammerhead#Taxonomy_and_phylogeny)).

Answer (score 1):

The "declension" table in Wiktionary is purely hypothetical; it does not prove that any of these forms actually occur in any text.

The attested abl. pl. tudibus implies nom. sing. tudis or tudes. It is normal lexicographic practice to lemmatize all nouns under a (real or hypothetical) nom. sing.

Comment: Could you expand a bit on why *tudibus* would be expected to go with nominative *tudis/tudes*? How can a form like *tus* (along the lines of *pes, pedibus; laus, laudibus; praes, praedibus*) be ruled out? Or would the form *tudites* be taken as evidence against that kind of nominative singular?

Comment: @sumelic. That is a good point.

Comment: _tus, turis_ is the word for incense or frankincense (used in a thurifer).

Comment: @TomCotton .... which does not rule out the existence of a homophone meaning "hammer".

Comment: Quite so. Just thought I'd point it out!

Comment: I guess the other d-stem nouns that I can think of that take -s rather than -es in the nominative singular all seem to have long vowels or diphthongs in that form: pēs, laus, fraus, praes. (Except maybe the disyllable pĕcus, ŭdis?) Maybe for some reason, a short vowel wouldn't be as likely in that context. But I guess I can't figure out how we know the vowel lengths in this word either: the quotes aren't in verse, are they?

Comment: @sumelic Off the top of my head, wouldn't ds > s cause compensatory lengthening?

Comment: @Draconis: I don't believe that there was a general principle of compensatory lengthening of vowels in nominative forms where -s combined with a preceding consonant to form a geminate (see [Alessio's answer here](https://latin.stackexchange.com/a/2621/9)). It looks like *-ds* in particular could possibly have lengthened a preceding vowel because d was originally a voiced stop, following the same pattern as "Lachmann's Law" (which traditionally refers to a vowel lengthening change in the context of past participle forms).